# restubbing method in OCMock does not seem to work?

Tags: ocmock

I am confused why this doesn't work...

```
[[[myObject stub] andReturnValue:@YES] isBadical];

NSLog(@"================> result: %i", [myObject isBadical]);

[[[myObject stub] andReturnValue:@NO] isBadical];

NSLog(@"================> new result: %i", [myObject isBadical]);
```

Result is:

```
2013-10-13 20:24:49.156 myApp[43197:c07] ================> result: 1
2013-10-13 20:24:49.157 myApp[43197:c07] ================> new result: 1
```

Is there a way to update the stubbed value without having to stop mocking and/or create a new mock object?

Answer (score 2):

Use `expect` instead of `stub`. AFAIK it's not possible to stub a method twice with OCMock. You don't need to send verify after executing the code you want to test since you are not interested in verifying any expectations.

Comment: This is correct. You should also call `setExpectationOrderMatters:YES` to make sure the expectations are applied in the right order.